# Call javascript method from Cordova Plugin's service

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, android-service, cordova-plugins

I am currently developing an App using Cordova and therefore have developed a Cordova Plugin, that runs a service and is being started from within that plugin:

```
  public boolean execute(String action, JSONArray args, final CallbackContext callbackContext) throws JSONException {
switch(action){
  case "start":
  Intent startIntent = new Intent(context, BackgroundService.class);
  startIntent.putExtra("action", "play");
  context.startService(startIntent);
  return true;
 }
return false;
}
```

The code is shortened for readability. Now normally I would use callbacks to call javascript methods from within the plugin, but as I want to use a service for the functionality, how could I call a method (or maybe the callback) from there?

Thank you very much in advance :).

Answer (score -1):

Okay so I did not find a way to this with vanilla cordova, but this Plugin provides the functionality I was looking for: https://github.com/bsorrentino/cordova-broadcaster

You have to set up a LocalBroadcastManager in your native Android Code and send an Intent with it. You then define a bundle containg the data you want to send, and put it as extra of your intent. Then you send the intent via the broadcast manager and receive it via javascript.

Sample Java:

```
  startCallback = new Intent("callback");
  Bundle b = new Bundle();
  b.putString("callback", "start");
  startCallback.putExtras(b);
  LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(applicationContext).sendBroadcastSync(startCallback);
```

Sample Javascript:

```
var callbackListener = function( e ) {
       console.log("What kind of callback: " + e.callback);
    };

window.broadcaster.addEventListener( "callback", callbackListener);
```

I hope this helps somebody with a similiar problem :).